# How to find IDLE source code (idlelib) in Mac?

Tags: python-idle

I'm trying to develop a custom extension for IDLE and have been following instructions to add my extension code to the idlelib folder and update the config-extensions.def file. However, I am on a Mac, and I understand these files are hidden from viewing. Curerntly, I'm able to edit the config-extensions.def file from my terminal (picture below), but I am unsure of where the rest of the source code is for launching IDLE, as I am unable to find the idlelib directory that has files such as zzdummy.py (the example extension for IDLE). It is my understanding that I need to add my custom extension file (called test.py) to the folder where the rest of this idle source code is located. I need help locating this folder on a Mac so I can add my file to the correct location.

In the picture below, I'm only able to see these four files (test.py is a file I added). However, I cannot locate the directory where I need to actually put my test.py file.

[config-extensions in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIx3h.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.idlerc/...` has user specific settings.  Notice `config-main.cfg` with user configurations.  `config-main.def` with defaults is in `<install-dir>/Lib/idlelib,`, which also has IDLE's .py files.  In IDLE, `File => Open module` brings up a dialog box.  Enter `idlelib.idle` and it will load `.../Lib/idlelib/idle.py` and the title bar should have the complete path where your custom extension should go.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me find it and i can continue developing and testing my extension code